# How to make my Perl module's README file compatible with Github's Markdown display?

Tags: perl, github, markdown, perl-module

I've authored the README file in my Perl module in Markdown. Github treats this README file as plain text. I tried renaming the file to "README.md"—which looks great on Github, but is invisible to Perl tools that look for a file named "README."

Is there any way I can have *both* a README file, and have my Markdown formatting be interpreted correctly by Github?

The only option I could come up with was to have both a README and a README.md, but I'd prefer not to have to manually keep the two files in sync.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Format your README in pod, rename it README.pod and then it [works](https://github.com/github/markup#markups) both places! [Example](https://github.com/jberger/Galileo)

For my purposes I actually just generate my README.pod from the main pod by doing

```
$ podselect lib/My/Main/Module.pm > README.pod
```

<s>One caveat, named external links don't work correctly `L<GitHub|http://github.com>` will unfortunately point to search.cpan.org looking for a GitHub module. I have tried to inform them of this glitch but it got me nowhere. Instead you can just use plain external links (i.e. `GitHub: L<http://github.com>`) and they work fine.</s>

Good news, it appears that they have fixed this since the last time I checked!

---

Just a question, what parts of the Perl toolchain expect a README file? If you mean including it in your tarball, just be sure to add the file to your MANIFEST and it should get included.

Comment: The only tools that I know of that care about "README" are websites like cpansearch and metacpan. I'm not sure about cpansearch, since the source isn't available, but I looked at metacpan, and it considers "README", "README.md", and "README.pod" all to be names of README files.

Answer (score 17):

Have you heard of [POD](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html)? This is the standard documentation tool in Perl. POD is a simple text documentation format that actually lives in your code. One of the commands that come with perl is [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldoc.html). You can use it to get the information of any Perl command. Try these:

```
$ perldoc File::Find
$ perldoc -f split
```

All Perl modules in [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org) are required to incorporate POD documentation. In fact, this is how the CPAN webpages themselves are built.

So, where am I going with this and how is this going to help you?

You should include POD documentation in your Perl program. Then, you can use the [pod2text](http://perldoc.perl.org/pod2text.html) command to create your README for your Perl program:

```
$ pod2text myperl.pl > README
```

That handles half of your issue.

The other half is a bit more tricky. You need to install from CPAN the [Pod::Markdown](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pod::Markdown) on your system. Then, you can run the [pod2markdown](http://search.cpan.org/~rwstauner/Pod-Markdown-1.321/bin/pod2markdown) command that comes with this module to create the markdown version of your file:

```
$ pod2markdown myperl.pl > README.md
```

The results:

- Your documentation lives, as it should, in your Perl program.
- Users can use the `perldoc` program to print out complete documentation of your program.
- You can use the `pod2text` tool to create your `README` file.
- You can use the `pod2markdown` tool to create your `README.md` file.
- As a bonus, you can use the [Pod::Usage](http://perldoc.perl.org/Pod/Usage.html) module that comes with Perl to show the POD documentation (or bits and pieces of it) as help text that's displayed when a user runs your program with the `-help` parameter.

So, one place where your documentation lives, and you're using a couple of helper programs to create the files Github and whatever *Perl tools* you use need.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind using [Dist::Zilla](https://metacpan.org/module/Dist::Zilla) you can pretty much do away with maintaining a README entirely.  For example [Dist::Zilla::Plugin::ReadmeFromPod](https://metacpan.org/module/Dist::Zilla::Plugin::ReadmeFromPod) can create your README file by extracting the Pod from your main module.  This means never having to write a README again.

I've never tried it myself, but you could look at something like [Dist::Zilla::Plugin::ReadmeMarkdownFromPod](https://metacpan.org/module/Dist::Zilla::Plugin::ReadmeMarkdownFromPod) to create your README automatically in markdown.

This may not be the exact answer you're looking for, but I think using this sort of a tool can save you a lot of time as it allows you avoid repeating yourself in your documentation.

Comment: Most Dist::Zilla plugins create the README file for the dist but not for the git repo, which is what you want for it to show up on Github. I use this:

    [ ReadmeAnyFromPod /MarkdownInRoot ]
    filename = README.md

Answer (score 0):

Another solution if you *really want* to distribute your module with a Markdown `README`, that doesn't involve Pod is to :

- rename your `README` file to `README.md`
- update the previous change in the `MANIFEST` file

I think it can be an interesting solution because more people know Markdown syntax than Pod one. As the aim of the README file is to be read by anyone, Markdown should be considered.

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking for a solution for this problem and decided to use [Dist::Zilla::Plugin::ReadmeAnyFromPod](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist::Zilla::Plugin::ReadmeAnyFromPod) as it understands `=attr` and `=method` tags from Pod::Weaver.

Answer (score -10):

> The only option I could come up with was to have both a README and a
>   README.md, but I'd prefer not to have to manually keep the two files
>   in sync.

Then automatically keep them in sync?

Comment: @ysth apparently, you have enough rep pts  to be a troll whenever you wish to be one :P