# How can I dynamically create files for a Perl distribution without manifest tests or makefiles complaining?

Tags: perl, manifest

I'm creating a Perl 5 module distribution, the source of which is hosted on github. I've run into the same problem as user Anirvan [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13188404/1317372): I'd like github to see a `README.md` file, but the `.tar.gz` to include the *same* file as plain `README`. The answer to that question, "use `README.pod` for both", works in this case, but I'm wondering if I could have made my original attempt work:

- I only have `README.md` in the repository, not `README`.
- My `MANIFEST` contains `README` (since that's going into the tarball), but not `README.md` (since it isn't).
- My `MANIFEST.SKIP` contains `README.md`, since I don't want that in the tarball.
- My `Makefile.PL` (*) has an entry under `PL_FILES` to a short script that copies the `README.md` to a `README` file

This generates the `README`, but along the way:

- `t/manifest.t` without `make` complains that `README` is in the manifest, but is missing
- `perl Makefile.PL` also complains about `README` missing

Am I misinterpreting the purpose of the `MANIFEST` file, or this test? Is it somehow possible to denote a file which should be packed, but isn't there yet? I've tried changing the test, but I could only find a way for `Test::CheckManifest` to ignore files that were there, but "shouldn't be", not ignore files that are not there, but "should".

<sub>(*) Yes, I'm using `ExtUtils::MakeMaker`, since that's what `module-starter` defaulted to, and it works so far. I'm not sure if another tool would change much, though.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

(Answering my own question here): `ExtUtils::MakeMaker`, `Module::Build` and the others are primarily **installation** methods. You should ignore what `make`, `Build` and the others are complaining about while building the distribution. It's what `make disttest` complains about that matters.

For that matter, do not place code to help build your distribution in `Makefile.PL`. You should only place code there that is to be run during **installation time**. So if you want `README.md` to become `README`, you had better distribute `README.md` too. This is obviously not what you want(*).

Instead, take a look at [Dist::Zilla](http://dzil.org/). This is explicitly a distribution creation system, and **not** an installation system.

<sub>(*) Replying to your own question can get really wierd… :-/</sub>